# How to recognize *ngFor index in td in angular4?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an array of dates to loop through which consist of all dates of 4 weeks as shown below:

```
          <table boder="1">
            <tr>
              <td>First Spot</td>
              <td *ngFor="let date of datesFullArray; let i = index;" class="nopadd" [class.no-border]="i+1 % 7 == 0">
                <div *ngFor="let gs of firstSpot">
                  <span [ngClass]="{
                                'available':checkDate(gs.fromDate, gs.toDate, date) === 1,
                                'not-available':checkDate(gs.fromDate, gs.toDate, date) === 0
                              }">
                    &nbsp;
                  </span>
                </div>
              </td>

            </tr>
          </table>
```

Here, i want to split the `<td>` i.e. when it reaches 1st, 2nd, 3rd weeks i want to apply `no-border` class which makes `border` as `none`.

I am trying to take the index value to do the same but not working..

Any help highly appreciated..

Comment: Code seems working fine , error must be somewhere else PLease check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p5twal?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I am trying to use in `table` `td` and applying class when the weeks are crossed..

Comment: that  is fine but there is no error in provided linked code as I shown in stackblitz.

Comment: i my code i have  used `*ngFor` and am checking the index value in the same `td` which is not getting recognized

Comment: @PardeepJain in the link you shared class to apply is missing and you are displaying the result within `<p>` and not in `<td>` like in my case

Comment: Can you please update your code there ?

Comment: Updated please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the border of td tag

using style binding

```
[style.border]="((i+1) % 7) == 0 && 'none'">
```

or class

```
[class.no-border]="((i+1) % 7) == 0">
```

demo [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-laejel?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)